# I want to have cold smoke emitting from bottle but can't get the settings right

Tags: smoke-simulation, mantaflow

So I want to make an ad video for my portfolio. It's a beverage bottle and I saw a tutorial on Youtube which was smoke from a cup of tea. It worked for the top part of the bottle and I tried to tweak it to have smoke kind of emitting from the bottle itself. But it didn't work.

It was this tutorial: "[How to Create Steam w/ Mantaflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_K0XsHht6pg)" by *Blender Made Easy*

I want the smoke to emit like this:
[image: I want the smoke to emit like this]

With current settings, the smoke emits out of the bottle but it's too much smoke. It's like it's on fire, while I want it to emit lower smoke so it seems like it's cold.

Also, let me know if those settings could be further optimized in any way.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to create is physically fog, not smoke. It's cold condensed water in the air that settles down and in this case, dissolves quickly.

To simulate cold gas there are these settings in the domain:

- [Buoyancy Density](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/physics/fluid/type/domain/settings.html#bpy-types-fluiddomainsettings-alpha) - values below 0 will cause smoke to sink. 
  → Give it a try and set this to `-1.0`
- Heat - controls how much smoke is affected by temperature. Values below 0 will result in the opposite of positive values, i.e. smoke emitted from flow objects with a positive *Initial Temperature* will sink, and smoke from flow objects with a negative Initial Temperature will rise. 
  → make this also negative, `-1.5`
- Vorticity - can add a bit turbulence, try `0.1`
- *Dissolve > Time* - if you lower this value the smoke will disappear faster. But you also can lower or even deactivate the *Wind Force Field* to keep the smoke closer to the bottle.

The bottle (gas inflow) has the

- *[Initial Temperature](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/physics/fluid/type/flow.html#bpy-types-fluidflowsettings-temperature)*. It's the difference between the temperature of emitted smoke and the domain’s ambient temperature. 
  → Keep it positive. You can experiment with it. I've increased it from `1.2` to `2.0`.

Test with the adjustments (frame 168, Cycles):

[image: test render 1]

With a shorter *Dissolve > Time* value of 10 frames:

[image: test render 2]

In the *Shader* you can adjust the values for the *Multiplier* nodes and the *ColorRamp* to control the visual appearance ("strength"/density) of the fog. I've lowered the values a bit, adjusted the values of the *ColorRamp* and set it to *B-Spline*:

[image: shader]

If you want to animate the condensate droplets this question might be helpful:
[How to animate metaballs as condesate drops](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238705/how-to-animate-metaballs-as-condesate-drops/238847#238847)

Comment: Thanks A lot man, never thought with this little tweaking it could be perfected, also that metaball drops is really dope, that should be on youtube tbh, But I have one question on Heat, as you mentioned "with positive values it will sink and with negative values it will rise" and we want our smoke to sink in this case then why did we used negative value ?